# Nginx setting fastcgi_cache_valid

Tags: nginx, cache, fastcgi

I have been trying to set 2 different cache times. I need a microcache for single request. And all other requests should be cached for longer time. All requests must go to location block, so that requests are being passed to PHP.

Error I receive running nginx -t:

> nginx: [emerg] invalid time value "$cache_time"

Here is part of my nginx conf server block:

```
set $cache_time 5m;
if ($request_uri ~ "myurl/\d*"){
    set $cache_time 2s;
}

location ~ \.php {
    fastcgi_cache MYCACHE;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 200 $cache_time;
    fastcgi_no_cache 0;

    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index /index.php;

    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Why does it say invalid $cache_time? Also tried '2s'. Am I not allowed to set it from variable at all? Any workarounds?

Comment: Probably because this value cannot be parametrized with variables.

Comment: You could use separate `location` for special url. Or, easier, use [`X-Accel-Expires`](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/#x-accel-expires) header from your PHP script

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work, because location is always index.php. I guess Phalcon framework does it. I don't know if it can be changed.

Comment: This issue has been discussed and solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30919396/

Comment: Jens there is nothing related to this issue there. Multiple location blocks were used and it is not an option here.